# CodeIgniter's "Removing the index.php file" is not working when CI is inside a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, codeigniter-2

I am using CI 2.1.4 (trying to use) when I edit .htaccess to remove the index.php from my url it doesn't work. My project is inside a subfolder:

http://myserver.dev/project/

I've set the base_url removed the index.php from $config['index_page'] = '' and pasted the exact code form http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/urls.html:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|images|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php/$1 [L]
```

Tried some solutions (some using RewriteBase) from stackoverflow.com fellows, but, it doesn't work.
How can I fix that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont think it's because of the .htaccess, this works for me and not because of the subfolder either.

This is an example of the .htaccess I'm using :

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^/(index\.php|assets/|humans\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Set the right url in the base_url or this :

```
$config['base_url']     = 'http' . ((isset($_SERVER['HTTPS']) && $_SERVER['HTTPS'] == 'on') ? 's' : '')
                  .'://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].str_replace('//','/',dirname($_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME']).'/');
```

And obviously :

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```

With this, it works for me...

Comment: Thank you very much, but it didn't work either.
Still getting "Error 404". Even with a recent extracted CI 2.1.4.

Comment: Apache configuration at /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf AllowOverride, for some reason, was set to None. Which would never load .htaccess config. A ghost, or myself (out of my mind) changed it. :)
Thanks a lot!

Comment: @tenshimsm please inform what have changed in your httpd.conf file so other people can see.